# nginx catchall subdomain not mapping to a specific map

Tags: nginx

I have a bit of problem with Nginx.
I want to use a wildcard subdomain that everythinghere.domain.com redirects to a specific map.

This is my currect Nginx setting (I replaced the domainname with domain.com):

```
server_name  domain.com www.domain.com 1.domain.com workspace.domain.com *.domain.com;

    root   /var/www/domain.com/web/;

    if ($http_host = "1.domain.com") {
        rewrite ^(?!/(1|stats|error|\.well-known/acme-challenge))/(.*)$ /1/$2 last;
    }
    if ($http_host = "workspace.domain.com") {
        rewrite ^(?!/(1|stats|error|\.well-known/acme-challenge))/(.*)$ /1/$2 last;
    }
    if ($http_host = "*.domain.com") {
        rewrite ^(?!/(1|stats|error|\.well-known/acme-challenge))/(.*)$ /1/$2 redirect;
    }
```

With above 1.domain.com and workspace.domain.com redirects (maps) correctly to the map /1/. The wildcard seems to work, but it doesn't map to /1/ but only to the root map.

So for example: 555.domain.com maps to root instead of /1/.

I think the problem is in the last 'if' line with the *.

Anyone a solution?

Thanks in advance!